# Using clicked data to populate box on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a form-like page, where a user must click a box (with data in) before you can submit and move on to the next page - however it is not a form post or anything (maybe someone can let me know if i am doing this the correct way?). However on the next page i want it to display the box that the user clicked at the top. Currently i can return all of the data that is clicked from the box, i just need a way of displaying the clicked box on the next page

Does anyone have any idea on how i would do this? I will attach some images to make this a bit clearer.

I have attached my first page HTML with the 4 boxes in, and the second HTML with the box at the top (currently hard coded in)

Please let me know if you need more information on this or if it looks a bit messy so i can tidy it up

Thank you!

[image: First page HTML Image, with the 4 boxes and the user must choose 1 before being able to move on the next page]

[image: Page 2, where the box at the top should be what the user clicked on the first page]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var data = [];
  //Currently gets the box ID
  $(".address-box").click(function () {

    var box = {};

    // get all the nested children
    var children = $(this).children('.address-data').children()

    // iterate through each and make an associative array with the text
    $.each(children, function (value) {
      var className = $(this).attr('class');
      box[className] = $(this).text();
    });
    console.log(box);
  });

  $("#next-step-button").on('click', function(){
    window.location='index2.html';

  });

});
```

```css
.address-box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.address-box-number{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.address-data {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.address {

font-size: 17px;

&__name{
  p {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  
} 

&__location {
  font-weight: 500;
}

}

.address-distance{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="Square1 address-box" id="box-1">
                <div class="address-box-number">1</div>
                <div class="address-data">
                    <div class="address address__name">
                        <span id="box-1-title">some text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address address__location">
                        <span id="box-1-title">more text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-distance">
                        <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Square2 address-box" id="box-2">
                <div class="address-box-number">2</div>
                <div class="address-data">
                    <div class="address address__name">
                        <p>CARL ROSNER MOTORCYCLES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address address__location">
                        <p>249 London Road, Romford, Essex, RM7 9NB</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-distance">
                        <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Square3 address-box" id="box-3">
                <div class="address-box-number">3</div>
                <div class="address-data">
                    <div class="address address__name">
                        <p>JACK LILLEY ROMFORD</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address address__location">
                        <p>59 - 61 Albert Embankment, Vauxhall, London UK, SE1 7TP</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-distance">
                        <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Square4 address-box" id="box-4">
                <div class="address-box-number">4</div>
                <div class="address-data">
                    <div class="address address__name">
                        <p>JACK LILLEY ASHFORD</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address address__location">
                        <p>249 London Road, Romford, Essex, RM7 9NB</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-distance">
                        <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
            
            
            
            //Next page box HTML
            
            <div class="address-box">

            <div class="address-data">
                <div class="address address__name">
                    <p>METROPOLIS MOTORCYCLES</p>
                </div>
                <div class="address address__location">
                    <p>59 - 61 Albert Embankment, Vauxhall, London UK,</p>
                    <p id="box1pc" value="SE1 7TP">SE1 7TP</p>
                </div>
                <div class="address-distance">
                    <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why not pass the information you need to the next page via query string. e.g. index2.html?id=123

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Rob, do you have any idea on how i would do this or point me in the right direction? I'm new to this stuff and unsure where to start

Comment: I do not know what you backend is. I can tell you how to do it if you are using ASP MVC but if it something else you will need help from people who are proficent in that technology.

Comment: Build the string in the block of code where you // iterate through each and make an associative array with the text

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do all the logic in client environment(browser) you must use some kind of storage to store the chosen option. You can implement this with: `cookies`, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` and even in browser SQL database(which is still not supported greatly).

When user selects the specific box, just store some kind of reference to it (ID) before you transfer him to another page. Based on that reference in next page read the stored value and act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

The box object consists of:

```
address address__location : 59 - 61 Albert Embankment, Vauxhall, London UK, SE1 7TP",
address address__name: JACK LILLEY ROMFORD",
address-distance: 000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)"
```

Now you need to take that information (but convert it to):

```
"?address__location=59 - 61 Albert Embankment, Vauxhall, London UK, SE1 7TP
 &address__name=JACK LILLEY ROMFORD
 &address-distance=000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)";
```

Attach that string to your redirect:

```
  $("#next-step-button").on('click', function(){
    window.location='index2.html'+box;
  });
```

In index2.html you will need to use JavaScript to get the information from the url. There is a good tutorial at sitepoint to do this extraction https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

Comment: Thank you for the response @jeff, so would i need to change the string itself to that?

So it would be 

<div class="address address__name">
       <p>&address__name=JACK LILLEY ROMFORD</p>
</div>

etc?